# Remove duplicates from range and use in for each loop

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create worksheets from a list in excel using VBA, I have the below code which works fine. But it doesn't remove duplicates from the list, and if I use remove duplicates, it throws an error. :). I don't want the original column altered.

```
Set MyRange = Sheets("YES").Range("A2")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates


For Each MyCell In MyRange




    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) ' creates a new worksheet
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = UCase(MyCell.Value) ' renames the new worksheet

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select ' selects current worksheet
    Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True ' changes fornt to bold
    ActiveCell.Value = ("Column Name") ' enters values into cell

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = UCase(MyCell.Value) ' enters column name in cell

Next MyCell
```

thanks

Comment: Did you remove the duplicates before you start the loop?...`Columns("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes`

Comment: Post the code that doesn't work that you want to fix, not (just) the code that already works ;)

Comment: I don't want the values removed from the original column?

Comment: *and if I use remove duplicates, it throws an error* - where's your attempt to do this? and what's the error you get it? show us that and we can help

Comment: I have updated the question, the error is "compile error, object required"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this code. It will leave the original column in tact and remove the dupes in a holding range. It's also qualified more cleanly.

```
Dim wsYes as Worksheet
Set wsYes = Worksheets("YES")

With wsYes

    Dim myRange as Range
    Set myRange = .Range("A2",.Range("A2").End(xlDown))

    myRange.Copy .Cells(1,.Columns.Count) 'copy to far right column
    .Cells(1,.Columns.Count).Resize(myRange.Rows.Count,1).RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo

    Set myRange = .Range(.Cells(1,.Columns.Count),.Cells(1,.Columns.Count).End(XlDown))

    For Each MyCell In myRange

        Dim sName as String
        sName = UCase(MyCell.Value)

        Dim wsNew as Worksheet
        Set wsNew = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)) ' creates a new worksheet
        With wsNew
            .Name = sName
            .Range("A1").Value = "Column Name"
            .Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
            .Range("A2").Value = sName
        End With

    Next MyCell

    myRange.Clear

End with
```

Comment: Hey seems to be exactly what im looking for!

Comment: I just get an error on this line Set wsNew = Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) it says it expects the end of the statement after sheets.add

Comment: @BenjiTaylor - try now

Answer (score 0):

Easy way (but not the best I think if you have many data):

```
Set MyRange = Sheets("YES").Range("A2")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

Dim index1 As Integer
Dim index2 As Integer

index1 = 0
For Each Cell1 In MyRange

    index1 = index1 + 1
    index2 = 0

    For Each Cell2 In MyRange 

        If index2 >= index1 
        Then Exit For

        If MyCell.Value = Cell2.Value 
        Then Goto NextCell1

    Next Cell2

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) ' creates a new worksheet
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = UCase(MyCell.Value) ' renames the new worksheet

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select ' selects current worksheet
    Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True ' changes fornt to bold
    ActiveCell.Value = ("Column Name") ' enters values into cell

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.Value = UCase(MyCell.Value) ' enters column name in cell

    NextCell1:
Next Cell1
```

Comment: No effectively (I'm on Linux so it's a bit difficult); try to understand and correct by yourself (It seems that I had a problem with the If statements (I **edited** but not tested one more time)